# how recovery of multiple downloaded image in formData with express?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, file-upload, multipartform-data

Hello sorry for my english, i have a little problem. i try to upload many images but in back side i have just one image, (i use React express formidable cloudinary) here is my code front :

```
 const [arrayFiles, setArrayFiles] = useState([]);

 const handleFiles = (e) => {
  let arrayUpload = [...arrayFiles];
  arrayUpload.push(e.target.files[0]);
  setArrayFiles(arrayUpload);
 };

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  arrayFiles.forEach((file) => {
  formData.append("image", file);
});

const response = await axios.post(
  "http://localhost:3100/offer/publish",
  formData
);
```

here is my code back  but req.files =>  just one image
my page route :

```
router.post("/offer/publish", async (req, res) => {


console.log(req.files);
const result = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.files.image.path, {
  folder: `api/leboncoin/offers/${newOffer._id}`, // _id vient de la création du newOffer au dessus
  public_id: "preview",
  cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_NAME,
});
```

my page index.js:

```
page index.js :

const express = require("express");
const formidable = require("express-formidable");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cloudinary = require("cloudinary").v2;
const cors = require("cors");


const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(formidable({ multiples: true }));
```

Comment: How are you processing the formData? Is it on multer?

Can you share the code on that part as well?

Most likely the middleware to process multipart form-data is not correct

Comment: I just modified but i dont use multer ! i use express-formidable !  I am a beginner, thx for your help

Comment: hm... can you double check that the formData from your frontend is actually an array of images?

Also, can you show a screenshot of how req.files looks like?

But still, I would recommend using multer, `express-formidable` seems to be dead for quite some time

Comment: It's ok now . Really thank you for your help and a hello from france

Answer (score 0):

You only get one file in `req.file` as you've set your `multer.single`

Using `multer`
There are 3 ways you can handle multiple file upload, each with a slightly different taste.

Assume you have a base multer

```
  const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: "public/data/",
    filename: function(req, file, cb){
      // You may change this to however you want, only affect your file name
      crypto.randomBytes(20, (err, buf) => {
        cb(null, buf.toString("hex") + path.extname(file.originalname))
      })
    }
  });

  const upload = multer({ storage: storage });
```

1. Use `.any()`

Accepts all files that comes over the wire. An array of files will be stored in `req.files`.
WARNING: Make sure that you always handle the files that a user uploads. Never add multer as a global middleware since a malicious user could upload files to a route that you didn't anticipate. Only use this function on routes where you are handling the uploaded files.

```
router.post("/offer/publish",upload.any(), async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.files); // Should give you an array of files
  // Do anything else
});
```

2. Use `.array(fieldname[, maxCount])`

Accept an array of files, all with the name `fieldname`. Optionally error out if more than `maxCount` files are uploaded. The array of files will be stored in `req.files`.

```
router.post("/offer/publish",upload.array('someFieldName', 10), async (req, res) => {
      console.log(req.files); // Should give you an array of files
      // Do anything else
    });
```

3. Use `.fields(fields)`

Accept a mix of files, specified by fields. An object with arrays of files will be stored in `req.files`.

fields should be an array of objects with name and optionally a `maxCount`. Example:

```
router.post(
  "/offer/publish",
  upload.fields([
    {
      name: "image",
      maxCount: 1,
    },
    {
      name: "audio",
      maxCount: 1,
    },
  ]),
  async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.files.image[0]); 
    console.log(req.files.audio[0]); 
    // Do anything else
  }
);
```

For your case, I would recommend going with Option 2.